# Play symbol with part variable name in actionscript.

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a random number variable called RandomNumber, and I want to play any of the symbols "fash0" to "fash5"

```
var RandomNumber = fl_GenerateRandomNumber(5);
```

And I was hoping I could do something like this

```
("fash"+RandomNumber).play();
```

Sorry if this question is very basic.

Comment: Is `flash0` a symbol name in library, or an instance name on the timeline?

Answer (score 0):

Untested but try as:

```
this["fash"+RandomNumber].play();
```

Comment: thank you this works, just without the dot. so 
this["fash"+tilfeldigTall].play();